Indexed db, localStorage and sessionStorage data stores at which path in Tauri
I have created a Windows desktop Application using Tauri and ReactJs, I am storing user data in the DB index using Dexie, but I am unable to find the data storage location (Where these data are being stored on the Windows file directory), and How can I change the storage location?

Tauri seem to use WebView2 on Windows which use Edge browser internally (while it uses Webkit / Safari engine on macos and linux). Edge browser probably stores the data in %LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Edge\User Data\Default.
https://tauri.app/v1/references/webview-versions/

Because of your answer, I got a starting point, thanks a lot

On Windows
The directory path where all the data related to IndexedDB, localStorage, and sessionStorage is stored as follows.
%LOCALAPPDATA%\<IDENTIFIER>\EBWebView\Default

For IndexedDB specifically, the complete path is
%LOCALAPPDATA%\<IDENTIFIER>\EBWebView\Default\IndexedDB\https_tauri.localhost_0.indexeddb.leveldb

note:
<IDENTIFIER> represents the identifier property value you gave in the tauri.conf.json file.
...
"identifier": "com.sample.application_name",
...

